# Laravel long loop over many objects dispatching jobs is timing out.

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, redis

I have 500 users.  I have to run through them all and assign different things, send them an email...

For each user I am sending a email, handling some api items.  This call is timing out after 30 seconds.

I am on Forge and so I have a redis working running.  I am very unfamiliar with queue'ing jobs and stuff like that so forgive the noob.

My handle() function in the job is:

```
public function handle()
{
    Log::info('hit the job');
// assign something
// hit an api and add something to the user
// send the user and email
// save user      

}
```

I am calling this from a controller:

```
 public function activateCohort(Request $request, $id)
{
    // Get some stuff

    foreach($users as $u){
         // do something 

            ProcessActivation::dispatch($u);    
    }


    // save some stuff


    return redirect()->back()->with('message-success', 'message');
}
```

This all runs fine. But it only goes through about 50 users.  In the future I need this to work for 1k, 2k, 5k users.

I am also not sure how to see how redis is doing.

I am at a loss for how to structure the call to work.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One thing I thought of is to batch process it. E.g., each job handles 50-100 users, so say you have 1000 users to send emails to, then you can have 10-20 jobs for that. Just my opinion.

Comment: Try to change max_execution_time=30 in php.ini to some bigger amount. Or better to use max_execution_time ( int $seconds ) in your script.